# Использование VLOOLUP вместе с QUERY и IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Подскажите пожалуйста, я делал отчёт используя SUMIF (ячейка C3), но сейчас понял, что если все листы за каждый месяц вставлять в один документ, то это будет не сильно практично и превышу лимит.
Поэтому решено на каждый месяц создавать отдельный документ и импортировать данные для расчёта.
Но оказалось, что SUMIF не работает с IMPORTRANGE :(
Изучив чат, понял что нужно делать через QUERY
Начал создавать формулу квери в ячейке H3, вроде бы в WHERE прописал все нужные условия, но выдаёт ошибку.
С чем это связанно, что сделал не так?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vb0cJbkjja537yl6HDYVcGiUUGZUgVAUiYcvstihMds/edit

Данные берутся от сюда:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WHuE9dYyCCtrcKrQmq4i4wx_KhimiPIo5KBLNNAsDSw/edit

Comment: Да какие Excel-формулы? Каким они боком к IMPORTRANGE? Google-таблицы - не Excel

Comment: @vikttur метку я поставил. Имея некоторый опыт работы как с excel, так и c google sheets, могу сказать, что многие формулы одинаковы. А что касается IMPORTRANGE - ну нет подходящей метки для гугл таблиц, не "запрос" же оставлять в самом деле?

Comment: А я могу с увереностью сказать, что `IMPORTRANGE` никаким боком к `Excel` не относится. Совершенно! Да, многие формулы одинаковы, но это РАЗНЫЕ программы. Вы же поставили метку *Excel-формулы*, но ни одной метки о Google-таблицах! И те, кто мог бы Вам помочь, запросто могут пройти мимо...

Comment: Так метки не я как раз ставил, и согласен, что несёшь тут явно не относится. 
Раз метки так важны - то добавил ещё метку :)

Comment: К сожалению, ваш пример не отражает сути. Вы просто прислали на дебаг свою проблему, чем нарушаете правила форума. Теги лишние

Answer (score 1):

### Пояснение к вопросу

`IMPORTRANGE` - является функцией импорта. Чем может сковать действия пользователя не только своими паузами по времени исполнения, но и отсутствием какого-либо представления об импортируемых данных.

`QUERY`, `VLOOKUP` и `SUMIF` - формулы другой категории, нежели `IMPORTRANGE`. И они в свою очередь разбирают типы данные по разному.

### Пояснения про типы

Типов в Таблицах немного. Основную проблему представляют "нечисла". Т.к. между числами и датами есть сильное сходство. А еще между форматами чисел и строк при бездумном форматировании ячеек может исчезнуть визуальная разница.

### Как использовать `IMPORTRANGE`

#### Ошибки из вопроса

Если взять "кусок" данных из примера и убрать форматирование, то видно, что в колонках смешанный тип данных. Строки, представляющие числа, числа и строки не числа.

Вот так работает `SUM` (взято для простоты формулы):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`QUERY`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`VLOOKUP` для точного поиска чисел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из примеров, формулы не только ломаются на смешанных типах, но и могут возвращать разные ошибки.

#### Особенность `IMPORTRANGE`

Пример переноса формата. Над таким иногда можно и голову поломать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Формула старается точно перенести типы, которые встречает. А также она переносит формат данных. Неожиданное поведение, которое, кстати, приводит к неожиданным результатам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Использование

Нет никакой необходимости в особенном использовании `IMPORTRANGE`, но существуют общепринятые рекомендации

- Импортируйте на отдельный лист. Разделяйте ответственность каждого листа, чтобы быстро отслеживать типы данных, расчеты и представления.
- Делайте "жадное импортирование". Откажитесь от `IMPORTRANGE` для колонок или небольших диапазонов. Лучше разобрать результат импорта уже в текущей Таблице
- По возможности, не импортируйте данные из листов "новогодних ёлок". Каша, полученная от "накидывания" и "раскрашивания" данных может сломать что-то, что будет после импорта. Создавайте наборы данных, которые однозначно показывают, какой тип на листе, сколько точек после запятой, это дата или дата-время.
- Если вы ожидаете далее рассчитывать в `QUERY`, то необходимо позаботиться о консистентности типов данных в колонках - формула не любит смешивание типов.

### Ответ

Разберитесь с типами данных в источнике.

Формулы на картинках отсюда https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9KfzdVhB42XS4_vI3XLE8lUpiF1-IB9cP_zl5yVj-M/edit?usp=sharing